# Getting an error while exceuting SQL query that contains dynamic parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

While executing the following SQL query

```
declare @OrderNumber  AS VARCHAR(10)
set @OrderNumber=('41973600','41973605') 

SELECT productid 
FROM [order] 
sono LIKE @OrderNumber
```

I am getting the errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near '@OrderNumber'

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're trying to accomplish can't be accomplished in this way.  You cant set a varchar(10) to multiple values, for that you need an "IN" clause, but here are different approaches to your problem:

I don't know what "sono" is, but it seems to be a column name based on your statement, so:

```
SELECT productid FROM [order] where sono in ('41973600','41973605')
```

Another option may be, if you are looking for wildcard:

```
SELECT productid FROM [order] where sono like '%41973600%' or sono like '%41973605%'
```

Finally, if you really want/need to declare @OrderNumber, then you need to do this:

```
declare @OrderNumber AS VARCHAR(10)
set @OrderNumber='41973600'
SELECT productid FROM [order] where sono= @OrderNumber

declare @OrderNumber AS VARCHAR(10)
set @OrderNumber='41973605'
SELECT productid FROM [order] where sono= @OrderNumber
```

Now, if "sono" is an alias for the table, then maybe you are looking to have:

```
SELECT productid FROM [order] sono where sono.productit in ('41973600','41973605')

SELECT productid FROM [order] sono where sono.productid like '%41973600%' or son.productid like '%41973605%'

declare @OrderNumber AS VARCHAR(10)
set @OrderNumber='41973600'
SELECT productid FROM [order] sono where sono.productid= @OrderNumber

declare @OrderNumber AS VARCHAR(10)
set @OrderNumber='41973605'
SELECT productid FROM [order] sono where sono.productid= @OrderNumber
```

I hope this helps.